# D3js v5 Zooming to Bounding box on geoMercator().fitSize()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis

I use this as reference: https://bl.ocks.org/iamkevinv/0a24e9126cd2fa6b283c6f2d774b69a2

Adjusted some syntax to fit for version 5

Scale works, Translate looks like it works too because if I change the value, it zooms on different place..

But the problem is it doesn't zoom on the correct place I clicked.

I think this doesn't get to the place correctly because I use `d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], geoJSONFeatures)` instead:

```
var bounds = path.bounds(d),
  dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
  dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
  x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
  y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
  scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height))),
  translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];
```

Already tried to change the values to fit mine but failed, I can't get it.

Here is my projection:

```
var width = 500;
var height = 600;

d3.json("/regions50mtopo.json")
  .then((geoJSON) => {

      var geoJSONFeatures = topojson.feature(geoJSON, geoJSON.objects["Regions.50m"]);

      // My Projection
      var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], geoJSONFeatures);

 ...
```

Any help, guide or reference?

> Note: I'm mapping different country and fitSize(...) solves the
>   problem easily to fit on my svg that's why I can't use the same as in
>   the reference link I provided.

Comment: Is it possible to show how you are using fitSize?

Comment: Hello @AndrewReid, I updated my post now with how I use the fitSize.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer: https://bl.ocks.org/veltman/77679636739ea2fc6f0be1b4473cf03a

```
centered = centered !== d && d;

var paths = svg.selectAll("path")
  .classed("active", d => d === centered);

// Starting translate/scale
var t0 = projection.translate(),
  s0 = projection.scale();

// Re-fit to destination
projection.fitSize([960, 500], centered || states);

// Create interpolators
var interpolateTranslate = d3.interpolate(t0, projection.translate()),
    interpolateScale = d3.interpolate(s0, projection.scale());

var interpolator = function(t) {
  projection.scale(interpolateScale(t))
    .translate(interpolateTranslate(t));
  paths.attr("d", path);
};

d3.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .tween("projection", function() {
    return interpolator;
});
```

Exactly what I'm looking for. It works now as expected.

But maybe somebody also have suggestions on how to optimise it, because as the author said too, it feels slow and "laggy" when zooming in/out.