# Why does d3.zoom not work correctly when using it with geo.json map data?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, zooming

Here is my map svg:

```
useEffect(() => {
 const svg = select(svgRef.current)

 const { width, height } = wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();

// projects geo-coordinates on a 2D plane
 const projection = geoMercator()
  .fitSize([width, height], data)
  .precision(100);

// takes geojson data,
// transforms that into the d attribute of a path element
 const pathGenerator = geoPath().projection(projection);
 initZoom()

// render each country
 svg
  .selectAll(".country")
  .data(data.features)
  .join("path")
  .attr("class", "country")
  .transition()
  .attr("fill", 'lightgrey')
  .attr("d", feature => pathGenerator(feature));
;
}, [data ]);
```

And here is the zoom logic:
let zoom = d3.zoom()
.on('zoom', handleZoom);

```
function handleZoom(e) {
 d3.select(svgRef.current)
  .attr('transform', e.transform)
}

function initZoom() {
 d3.select(svgRef.current)
  .call(zoom);
}
```

Instead of zooming in around the mouse pointer like with examples, it instead zooms out from the bottom right corner. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can find hint at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980074/d3js-v5-zooming-to-bounding-box-on-geomercator-fitsize

Comment: Is svgRef an SVG or a `g` element? Will be useful in making an answer demonstrating the issue and solution.

Comment: @AndrewReid svgRef is an SVG